# Same encryption method of openssl_encrypt with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption

An API I am working with only accepts encrypted JSON object data with the openssl_encrypt formula below:

`data = openssl_encrypt(body, 'aes-256-cbc', ciphertext+api_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, ciphertext)`

All responses from the API are also encrypted in this same way. Is it possible for me to achieve the same encryption format with CryptoJS so that the API will accept my encrypted data requests?

Here is what I have with CryptoJS at the moment.

```
var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(body), 'aes-256-cbc', ciphertext + apikey, ciphertext);
var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData.toString(), 'aes-256-cbc', ciphertext + apikey, ciphertext);
var decryptedObjectData = JSON.parse(decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
console.log(decryptedObjectData);
```

When I encrypt my data and decrypt it with this code, it works. But when I receive encrypted data from the API and try to decrypt it with this CyptoJS, it tells me I have malformed UTF-8. Similarly, when I try to encrypt my data with CryptoJS to be accepted by the API, I get a 'Bad Request' response, meaning the encryption isn't accepted.

I am doing it via CryptoJS because I am new to encryption and do not know how to use openssl_encrypt with my application. But if someone can teach me, that would be great. I don't know how to run openssl_encrypt in php on my server and have my JS application run it. Is AJAX the way to call on a script on the server on your application?

Comment: Your names are very confusing. Where it says "ciphertext" it should say "iv". Have you verified that iv+apiKey is actually exactly 32 bytes long (because if it isn't CryptoJS assumes it's a passphrase and derive the key from that). And for the record: the "formula" is pseudo-PHP code referring to [openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php).